# Xaringan: Extra character in panel

Tags: r, panel, xaringan

New to Xaringan and StackOverflow.  Had a hard time figuring out how to create tabs (panels) on slides given the info available in the instructions.  But, I have it working.  However, there is a `]` below the title on every Panel slide.  Why?  This seems to be causing my text to go off the bottom of the slide.  I think if I could remove it, then the slides would shift upwards and there would be enough space for my content to fit on the slide.

[image]

[image]

I have tried removing various `]` brackets, but depending on which one I remove, it either removes panels and overlaps all of the content on one slide with the tables and graphs or it deletes the panel and all the content from the panel.

At first, I was unable to make more than one slides with panels.  The first slide worked perfectly fine and did not have the random `]` at the top of it.  But the second slide would not create panels.  It just threw all of the content overlapping on one slide.  I was able to create two slides with panels when I found

div solution
[here](https://pkg.garrickadenbuie.com/xaringanExtra/#/panelset)
, but that is when the issue with the `]` started appearing.  The `]` is not part of the content.

In reality, there are 4 tabs per slide in roughly the following format:

- Tab 1: content and image
- Tab 2: R code reactable table
- Tab 3: conent and imate
- Tab 4: R code ggplot2 plotly interactive graph

I expect one slide with 4 tabs that can be clicked on, but without the extra space or extra characters between the title and the tabs.

***EDIT***

I put my code here, but someone changed it and it no longer reflected what I had written.  I deleted it because it was no longer my code.  I also found something in the source code. There is clearly a

]

in the source code.  How do I find that file and remove it from the source code?

[image]

Comment: I tried to fix your formatting for you. It looks like you did a find + replace all that put escapes before _all_ the "]" characters, which you probably didn't intend. I'm not sure what's up with that / which are intentional so I didn't touch those

Comment: Thank you.  I had some trouble with typing the information.